# Unable to install BigBlueButton Turn Server

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have a brand new Ubuntu Server running Version 20.04

I have Executed the following command

wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install-2.6.sh | bash -s -- -c xxxxx.xxx.com:secretcode -e email@address.com

I am receiving the following errors

main: line 1713: /etc/bigbluebutton/turn-stun-servers.xml: No such file or directory
chown: invalid group: ‘root:bigbluebutton’
chmod: cannot access '/etc/bigbluebutton/turn-stun-servers.xml': No such file or directory

any help would be appreciated

I expected a clean install

Comment: Does that file exist and do you have permissions on it? This also doesn't appear to be a programming-related question.